# how to get rid of the border appearing at the bottom of the svg?

Tags: css, svg

I am trying to work with a wave SVG. The problem I am facing is that I get a border at the bottom and I want to remove it.

Here is my JSX code:

```
<DarkWave>
  <svg data-name="Layer 1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 1200 120" preserveAspectRatio="none">
     <path d="M321.39,56.44c58-10.79,114.16-30.13,172-41.86,82.39-16.72,168.19-17.73,250.45-.39C823.78,31,906.67,72,985.66,92.83c70.05,18.48,146.53,26.09,214.34,3V0H0V27.35A600.21,600.21,0,0,0,321.39,56.44Z"
           class="shape-fill"></path>
     </svg>
</DarkWave>
```

Here is the CSS part:

```
export const DarkWave = styled.div`
    width: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
    line-height: 0;
    height: 95vh;
    background-color: #705df2;
    transform: rotate(180deg);
    margin-bottom: 5rem;

    svg {
        position: relative;
        display: block;
        width: calc(100% + 1.3px);
        height: 127px;
        
    }

    path.shape-fill {
        fill: #ffffff;
    }
`;
```

I tried to make the stroke as transparent but it didn't work:

```
svg{
 .........
 stroke: transparent;
 stroke-width: 0px;
}
```

Here is the image of the problem:

[image]

Please guide me.

Answer (score 0):

When you stretch the SVG the edges will "anti-aliase".

In this example I kind of turned around the transparent/ colored part and made a mask that controls the visible part. I also run into the same problem, but now it is easier to make a overlap (inside the mask).

```css
div {
  width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin-bottom: 5rem;
}

svg {
  display: block;
  height: 95vh;
  width: 100%;
}

svg>rect {
  fill: #705df2;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 1200 712" preserveAspectRatio="none">
    <defs>
      <mask id="m1">
        <rect width="1200" height="1200" fill="black" />
        <rect width="1200" height="601" fill="white" />
        <!-- above height 601 = overlap to -->
        <path transform="translate(0 600)" d="M321.39,56.44c58-10.79,114.16-30.13,172-41.86,82.39-16.72,168.19-17.73,250.45-.39C823.78,31,906.67,72,985.66,92.83c70.05,18.48,146.53,26.09,214.34,3V0H0V27.35A600.21,600.21,0,0,0,321.39,56.44Z" fill="white" />
      </mask>
    </defs>
    <rect width="1200" height="1200" mask="url(#m1)" fill="white" />
  </svg>
</div>
```